# Excel create an Index on the first sheet with links to subsequent sheets

Tags: excel, vba, office-js, office-scripts

I have a Workbook with 12 Worksheets.  The first Worksheet is the Index, the 11 other sheets contain data relative the index.  This Workbook references a file tree structure, what I am trying to do is link all Folder names to their respected Worksheet.  I have labelled these folders as 'Folder 1, Folder 2' etc.  In reality the folder names are all unique.

The table below is the folder tree.

[image]

I need to name the worksheets based on their breadcrumbs.  So For example Folder 3 Would be

> Folder 1>Folder 2>Folder 3

With the limit being set as 31 characters, Any directories 6 deep with long names wouldn't fit.  So I have the table below.

[image]

How would I go about doing this?  The worksheets are in order, I just need to batch rename based on their path and link to the first table, so when they click on Folder 8, they will hit tab F1.F6.F8

Comment: Please, show us what you tried by your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a potential duplicate of [Excel - Hyperlink to a worksheet which name is found in a cell](https://superuser.com/a/1512970/1178824) over at Stackoverflow Superuser

This answer shows how to use the Hyperlink function in excel to take a value from a cell (your worksheet name column) and using this to link to another tab

=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#", [cellcontainingthetabname], "!A1"), [textyouwishtodisplay])